# RSA Encrypting with node.js gets BadPaddingException in Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt some data in node to send to a Java server and keep coming up with this error BadPaddingException.  I've seen other posts with an answer to change the Cipher instance on the Java side

```
Cipher CheckCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

but since this server is used for several different services, this isn't possible for this application.

My current implementation is using node-forge

```
var publicKey = fs.readFileSync('Public.key', 'utf8');
const key = new nodeRSA([publicKey]);    //the file is not pem formatted and nodeRSA formats it to use in forge
var publicKeyForge = forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(key.exportKey(scheme));
var providerIdBufferForge = forge.util.createBuffer(providerId, 'utf8');  
var providerIdBytes = providerIdBufferForge.getBytes();
var providerIdEncrypted = publicKeyForge.encrypt(providerIdBytes, 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');
var encryptedProviderId = forge.util.encode64(providerIdEncrypted);
```

however this is coming up with the padding error on the Java side.

I've also tried using node-rsa, and crypto.publicEncrypt.  I'm pretty certain that this is a mismatch in the algorithm scheme, but after a couple days of trial and error, still coming up empty.

The Java side code is

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
byte[] byteDecryptText = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(dataToDecrypt);
decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(byteDecryptText);
decryptedData = new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");
```

Does anyone have any experience with matching node RSA Encryption with the basic Java RSA Decryption?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please don't rely on default behavior of your Cipher. You need to be in control on what options are in play, or you end up with questions like this. You should be able to formulate exactly what padding is used in both ends and then specify it in your code. Not specifying the padding on the Cipher in java because the code it's already in use is just a bad excuse .. An option is in play, so specify it .. and when that is in place, you then automatically also know what option to use in your javascript.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't at least test the server with the complete RSA transformation string. In any event the Oracle providers default to PKCS1PADDING so that isn't your problem. Most likely you're using the wrong private key, or garbling the data somewhere along the line,

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen the Java code was written years ago and is maintained by a different group so I really don't have any choice.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I agree with the data getting garbled somewhere, though I'm using the example code direct from Forge so I'm not really seeing where it's gone wrong.  Pretty certain the keys are right given that I do have direct access to the developers.  Any suggestions on where the data could have gotten corrupted?

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to show a complete example with private keys (throw-away test keys of course) and the inputs and outputs to the node and Java sides of the problem.

Comment: RobMillerJ25@, Did you get solution for this issue ?

Comment: @saurabhagarwal it ended up being an issue with the formatting of the certificate as a string in js.  I can't remember off the top of my head, but I think there was an issue with the \r or \n or \r\n and the number of characters in each row, the key was given to me as just a single line string.  Hope that helps.